# Android: In a multi-threaded Service, is LocalBroadcastManager safe?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, service

In a multi-threaded Service is `LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast()`, called from different threads, already thread-safe?

```
public class MyService extends Service
{
    // [...] define binder to allow access to doSomething() and doSomethingElse(), etc.

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) 
    {
        return binder;
    }

    public void doSomething() 
    {               
        new Thread(new Runnable() 
        {           
             public void run() 
             {
                // [...] do something

                // TODO is this threadsafe??
                LocalBroadcastManager broadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
                broadcastManager.sendBroadcast(new Intent(DONE_SOMETHING));
            }
        }).start();
    }

    public void doSomethingElse()
    {               
         new Thread(new Runnable() 
         {          
             public void run() 
             {
                 // [...] do something else

                 // TODO is this threadsafe??
                 LocalBroadcastManager broadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
                 broadcastManager.sendBroadcast(new Intent(DONE_SOMETHING_ELSE));
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Or `LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this)` returns actually always the same instance for the same context and is not otherwise synchronized, so I actually need to add a level of synchronization around the `LocalBroadcastManager`, with something like:

```
MyService extends Service
{
    private class SyncedLocalBroadcastManager
    {       
        private LocalBroadcastManager broadcastManager;

        SyncedLocalBroadcastManager(LocalBroadcastManager manager)
        {
            broadcastManager = manager;
        }

        public synchronized void send(Intent intent)
        {
            broadcastManager.sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
    }

    private SyncedLocalBroadcastManager syncedBroadcastManager; 

    // [...] define binder to allow access to doSomething() and doSomethingElse(), etc.

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) 
    {
        syncedBroadcastManager = new SyncedLocalBroadcastManager(LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this));

        return binder;
    }

    public void doSomething() 
    {               
        new Thread(new Runnable() 
        {           
             public void run() 
             {
                // [...] do something

                syncedBroadcastManager.send(new Intent(DONE_SOMETHING));
            }
        }).start();
    }

    public void doSomethingElse()
    {               
         new Thread(new Runnable() 
         {          
             public void run() 
             {
                 // [...] do something else

                 syncedBroadcastManager.send(new Intent(DONE_SOMETHING_ELSE));
            }
        }).start();
    }

}
```

Or is there any other preferred/canonical way?

I wouldn't want to add unnecessary synchronization in an already complex structure, but I cannot find any confirmation.

Comment: If your final goal is to call `sendBroadcast` then I think it works in an atomic way so no sync is needed. I.e. sending a broadcast you cannot interfere with other broadcast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is thread safe, Here code snippet from actual class getinstance mehtod :

```
public static LocalBroadcastManager getInstance(Context context) {
    synchronized (mLock) {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new LocalBroadcastManager(context.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return mInstance;
    }
}
```

Hence you can use this without any sync overhead.

Comment: If I read this correctly, the lock is only around the creation, but any following time getInstance() is called, the same mInstance is returned, and hence it could be NOT thread-safe to use it, unless the same lock is inside sendBroadcast(), which could be. I understand this is quite beside the point of this question but: should I actually depend on the current implementation, looking "under" what is presented as an API and beside what is documented? Could it change in the future? Is this documented somewhere? If so, how can I verify that also the sendBroadcast() synch on mLock inside itself?

Comment: @GozzoMan  yes, your point is correct, But locking is also present in sendbroadcast(), where lock for mReceivers(Hashmap of registered receivers ) is taken before broadcasting.
APIs are developed as for future use and taking care all possibles scenarios, So I don't think there is so frequent updates to APIs unless untill they are highly unstable or some big design issue.

Comment: Android source code is openly available, you can check it on github
https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.java